# eclipselink doesn't fetch list

Tags: java, orm, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

there are two entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Place implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place")
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    private String name;
//getters setters
}
@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event" , cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<Participant>();
    @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.EAGER) private Place place;
    private String name;
// getters setters
}
```

the generated tables:

```
mysql> desc EVENT;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PLACE_ID | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> desc PLACE;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| LOCATION | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NAME     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, I'll code some Java so the Place and Event tables looks in this way:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | NAME   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Prague |
+----+--------+
+----+-------------+----------+
| ID | NAME        | PLACE_ID |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 | Programming |        1 |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Now, I would like to pick a place and view all its events:

`// there's an ejb talking with persistence layer 
Place p = ejb.getPlaceWithId(1);`

and I would think that there's something more than empty collection in `p.events`, but there is not - based on my observations. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I would like to pick a place and view all its events (...) and I would think that there's something more than empty collection in p.events, but there is not - based on my observations. Why?

My observations are that the `events` are `LAZY` in the code you're showing:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "place")
private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
```

So how did you come to the conclusion that they are empty when loading a given `Place` exactly? Did you try to call `size()` on the collection to force the loading (or to iterate on collection items)?

Regardless of the answer to the above question, my suggestions would be to

- Activate SQL logging (and to run the queries in a SQL client if necessary) to see what is happening.
- Maybe actually use a `fetch join` if you want to load the `events` eagerly:

  ```
  SELECT p FROM Place p join fetch p.events WHERE p.id = :id
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling p.getEvents().size() or are you inspecting the attribute in a debugger?  If it is in a debugger then you may be seeing the Lazy loading artifacts which will be empty until the collection is accessed.  Try calling p.getEvents().get(0) and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "place", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
```

does it.

2) or

```
Place p = ejb.getPlaceWithId(1);
p.getEvents().size(); // will force the fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem in your EJB method getPlaceWithId - not sure how you're looking up your entities.

Comment: no, It actually works as expected with hibernate and FetchType.EAGER, there must be some problem with the eclipse link...

Comment: which version of EclipseLink are you using?